# uniform convergence of series of functions $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

The series of functions given is

> $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

is uniformly convergent on any closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$

**solution I tried**-we know that $$\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos x$$

so here the given series is $$1+\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos x$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos x -1$$

what can I say about convergence?
Is there any another method to prove its uniform convergence, these questions are very tough to solve

Please help

Comment: Good noticing about $\cos$.  What methods have you used (or seen) to solve uniform convergence problems before?

Comment: Dini's,Abel and Dirichlet's test. $M_n$ test

Comment: Well, then, you have the tools you need.   In uniform convergence problems it helps to use worst-case reasoning.  Which $x$ values would cause the worst problem for convergence?

Comment: i only know the test ,but sometimes it is very tough to apply and find out which method will be suitable.Same is happening in this problem.

Comment: Maybe you've seen a treatment of a series similar to your $\cos$ series, but a little simpler?  If so, maybe you can modify that argument.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:
I am sure you noticed that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ is a power series. A power series converges uniformly in any closed interval 
$[a,b] \subset (-R,R), R $ here being the radius of convergence. Not sure if you are familiar with this theorem, it is an immediate consequence of Weierstrass M-test, so convince yourself that it works before you use it!. So to conclude your proof, you may continue this way:

1. find the radius of convergence of your power series (you already know it converges to $cos(x)$, which basically gives you the answer immediately)
2. Prove and use the theorem I mentioned

Comment: Here radius of convergence of the series is $\infty$ so it will be convergent somewhere in the subset of $(-\infty,\infty)$ and here $[a,b]$ is subset of this interval so given series is uniform convergent ?

Comment: Exactly. Now just see what the theorem claims - do you see why it works?

Comment: Maybe you mean if the closed interval is contained in the *interior* of the domain of convergence?  I'm not sure whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ is uniformly convergent on $[-1, 0]$ - and even if it is, the proof won't be as simple as an application of Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Not sure about your series, but of course there are more trivial counterexamples if you consider the phrasing I used. Edited, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

In the interval $[a, b]$ it is true that $\lvert x \rvert^{2n} \leq (\max(\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert))^{2n}$. Hence,

$$\bigg \lvert \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \bigg \rvert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(\max(\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert))^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

The series on the right hand side is convergent by the ratio test. Therefore, by the Weierstraß M-Test, the series on the left hand side converges uniformly on the interval $[a, b]$.